# Port number for connecting web3 to mainnet using Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, ethereum-classic, geth-debugging

I am trying to connect web3j  object to the mainnet using geth. I can't use infura because i am working with replay transaction observable function which doesn't work with infura. To connect with the testnet we use port 8545, **what port number should we use to connect to the mainnet**. Also, is it necessary that all the blockchain should be allowed to synchronize before I start using the mainnet?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `geth` with any port you like, and connect with `web3j` to that port. The network `geth` connects to is not defined by the port it exposes for `rpcapi`:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

```
API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS:
  --rpc                  Enable the HTTP-RPC server
  --rpcaddr value        HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
  --rpcport value        HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545)
```

so you can use the same 8545 as for mainnet or, if you like, establish your own internal convention and always run `geth` with another port, like `8747`, when connecting to testnet.

Comment: Is complete synchronisation necessary before running the code?

Comment: Depends on your code. If you mean "deploy the code", then, AFAIK, syncing with at least `--syncmode=fast` helps to speed up the process and make it more reliable, but `--syncmode=light` is enough too.

Comment: No, i just want to use a replay transaction function which replays transaction history between 2 blocks.

Comment: I believe it's still a yes. I synced before events worked for me. Check related question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/29681/11501